# Google Photos Add a Location on Multiple Files

Tags: photos, google-plus-photos

I am using Google Photos for my archieved photos. I have lots of photos from past(When the Photo Location not involved)
Now i want to add the location for my Photos to organize them. 
It is possible for 1 image. But there thousands of them. Is there possible way to do it Folder by Folder or Multiple Photos Selection and Add Location to them?[image]

Comment: You could download them, use something like [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to change the metadata (like location), then reupload.

Answer (score 2):

This can only be done through desktop on Picasa web albums as far as I know, but Picasa shares photos with Google Photos, so it should work.

1. Put all your photos with the same location in an album (you can do this with Google Photos)
2. Go to Picasa Web Albums and find the album.
3. Under "Actions", click "Album map"

[image: Step 3]

4. This will bring you to the album map. Once there, click "Edit map"

[image: Step 4]

5. Click the first picture in the album to select it, then while holding <kbd>shift</kbd> click the last picture in the album.

[image: Step 5]

5. Drag the pictures out onto the map. You may want to find your location first.

[image: Step 6]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the photos on you android you can use the android app https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/ . it has multi-selection support and you can use a map to select the geo-location you want to assign.

Unfortunately the app only works with photos that are stored on the android device.

The free app is not available on google play store but you can get it via [f-droid](https://f-droid.org/) or download it via https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=de.k3b.android.androFotoFinder

Howto geotag the photos

- Start the app in gallery view
- use the "filter" menu/icon to find photos you want to tag:

  - filter by folder and/or date range
  - additionaly select "[X] With no geo info"
- ==> the gallery is populated with all photos that do not have a geo-tag yet
- via multiselection mark all photos that should recive the same geo location.

  - long tap on the first image ==> it is marked with "[V]"
  - short tap on additional images from the same location
- use the "set geo" menu to start tagging

  - select "pick from map" if you want to pick the geo-location from a map
  - select "pick from photo" if you want to pick the geo-location from a photo that has geo-location