# Add Location to Photos

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, photos, 5.1-lollipop, moto-x, google-plus-photos

I know this is possible with third party applications, but is it not possible to add location to an image using the standard Google Photos app, either from the website or mobile app ? Just realized I had the location turned off on my Camera app after a trip, and would like to be able to search the pictures by location.

I have seen [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106960/google-photos-add-a-location-on-multiple-files) which suggests there is a way, although I believe this is an older version as I cant find that option anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's not possible using the standard google photos app, you would need to use some photo-processing software to set locations for photos after they were taken (Picasa comes to mind). Alternatively, you can use the G+ page https://plus.google.com/photos/yourphotos to edit the GPS information, but then again i'm afraid you can only do this one by one. Maybe it's best to just turn on the location feature while taking the photos and you're done

Comment: for tagging multiple photos at one, hava a look at [Geo Picture Map](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shuewe.picturemap) – IMHO the easiest variant. Unfortunately, "just turn on the location feature while taking the photos" isn't an option anymore for photos already shot (as OP explained, he did not incidentally turn it off, and the photos in question have already been taken).

Comment: of course that will relate only to future shots

Comment: Exactly. But that's known to the OP – who explicitly asked for photos already taken, not for future ones ;)

Comment: i've also came across this program http://www.geosetter.de/en which basically does exactly that. I find Picasa easier to work with thats why i recommended it in the first place